Using Powershell to list the cores that each thread of a process is running on
Linux systems have a command ps -mo pid,tid,psr -p<PID> that lists all the threads of a process with Id <PID> and the processor cores that the threads are running on.
For example:
ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p5301
    PID     TID %CPU PSR
   5301       - 16.9   -
      -    5301 10.3   0
      -    5302  0.0   2
      -    5303  0.0   1
      -    5304  0.2   3

I'm looking to doing the same thing with PowerShell here is how far I have come. The only relevant property that I have been able to find is the ProcessorAffinity and thread-affinity but I don't think that's what I need.
(Get-Process -Id 21112).Threads | Format-Table 'Id'

   Id
   --
 9992
27356
21836
14740
16252
 2100

select-Object -property * does not fare much better, e.g.
(Get-Process -Id 27512).Threads | select-Object -property *


BasePriority            : 8
CurrentPriority         : 9
Id                      : 12292
IdealProcessor          :
PriorityBoostEnabled    : True
PriorityLevel           : Normal
PrivilegedProcessorTime : 00:00:01.8750000
StartAddress            : 0
StartTime               : 10/06/2024 09:04:02
ThreadState             : Wait
TotalProcessorTime      : 00:00:06.2500000
UserProcessorTime       : 00:00:04.3750000
WaitReason              : UserRequest
ProcessorAffinity       :
Site                    :
Container               :

...


Use following to get additional properties :  get-process | select-Object -property *

@jdweng select-Object -property * does not seem to initialize the any of the properties I am interested in.

Try without Threads.  You are only getting the child processes and not the parent.
